# Download Polymer elements directly

Tags: polymer, bower

At the moment I want to create a small web application with Polymer. For the main UI I want to use the paper elements and as long as version 0.5 was actual we were able to download all these elements from the website and use them in our project. Now with version 1.0 if I look at the Polymer website there is only an install introduction with bower. I'm on windows so I have no real installation of bower and python. Is there a way to downloads the elements manually? If I look at the Polymer GitHub page I only see a bower.json file but I want to download the elements direcly.

Comment: It's possible to use [bower in Windows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower#windows-users) (but it's not quite as easy as in linux or osx). It doesn't depend on python, but you need node.js and npm installed locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still download them by visiting the Paper elements project page at https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements

[image]

Click on the `<>` icon to navigate to the Github page and then click on `Download ZIP` in bottom right to download the element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can get them from this location:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/

Comment: But for example the paper-input also have only a Bower.json file or am I wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking at but you can get whole package (https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input). If you are not using bower you will need to download dependencies separately. You can get bower for windows if you want to. It is very convenient.